# Azure Service Bus library is spamming console

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used the tutorial provided by microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues

Everything checks out, yet I am not only seeing the "sent message" and "received message" console logs.
The console is printing everything, like every call the library is doing.

[image]

The application is encapsulated in a docker container, but that shouldn't trigger this behavior.
I also changed the logging from True to False

```
 ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=False)
```

But there is no change in behavior. It keeps spamming the console.
How can I change the logging behavior of the azure package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for anyone encountering this issue:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/9422